# Nginx error nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash with zimbra

Tags: nginx

I have installed Zimbra 8.6 on CentOS 7 and I have changed the

```
zmprov modifyConfig zimbraFileUploadMaxSize 5000000
zmprov mcf zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize 52428800
```

I have restarted the mailbox

the I can't access to my Zimbra webmail with the proxy address so i have checked the proxy server and I have restarted it.

Then I have this issue

```
Starting zmconfigd...Done.
Starting memcached...Done.
Starting proxy...Failed. Starting nginx...nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64 failed.
```

I have followed [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_names_hash_bucket_size) article
and I changed it and no way.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html), this might help you

Comment: I have seen it but no way. i can't reload or execute  # nginx -t

Comment: what changes have you made so far. show us the output of `nginx -t `

Comment: i have edited the /opt/zimbra/nginx/conf/nginx.conf and i added this two lines on http section :  server_names_hash_max_size 512;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;  #nginx -t the output is -bash: nginx: command not found

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys i have solved the problem like this :

```
# su - zimbra

$ zmlocalconfig -e proxy_server_names_hash_max_size=4096
$ zmlocalconfig -e proxy_server_names_hash_bucket_size=512

$ zmproxyctl start
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the size of the hash table as an when you increase the server

It depends on your setup, you can reduce the number of server from the table and `reload` the service instead of restart.

`service nginx reload`

server_names_hash_max_size

Its default value is 512. If you are hosting hundreds of sites on your server.

Nginx suggests, you can change either `server_names_hash_max_size` or `server_names_hash_bucket_size` to accomodate large number of sites, but I prefer keeping `server_names_hash_bucket_size` as it is and making `server_names_hash_max_size` big in multiple of 2’s till error disappears.

On a server, where we host 300+ sites, we needed to change it to `8192`

Use a trick to find out correct size by using following command:

`ls /etc/nginx/sites-available/ | wc -c`

Comment: hi, there is not this directory (/etc/nginx/sites-available/) in zimbra i have /opt/zimbra/nginx/conf/nginx.com and /opt/zimbra/conf/nginx.conf